# I want to Extract date part from File MUNDIPHARMA_HospitalPROFITS_20230228.zip in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-synapse

I have these Many files want to store them in a date folder format like yyyy folder then mm folder then dd folder then i want to place files in it
[image]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to copy the above files to its respective folders, you can follow this approach.

These are my source zip files.

[image]

I have given it to Get Meta data using a binary dataset and got child items array and passed to foreach. Inside ForEach, I have extracted the year, month and date from the filename using split and substring and copied to respective folders.
This is my pipeline flow.

[image]

These are my Binary datasets for the copy activity source and sink.

**Source:**

```
{
    "name": "copybinarysource",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureDataLakeStorage1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "filename": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "Binary",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
                "fileName": {
                    "value": "@dataset().filename",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "folderPath": "input",
                "fileSystem": "data"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Sink:**

```
{
    "name": "sinkbinary",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureDataLakeStorage1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "folder_name": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "file_name": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "Binary",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
                "fileName": {
                    "value": "@dataset().file_name",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "folderPath": {
                    "value": "@dataset().folder_name",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "fileSystem": "target1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is my pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Get Metadata1",
                "type": "GetMetadata",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "Binary1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "fieldList": [
                        "childItems"
                    ],
                    "storeSettings": {
                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                        "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                    },
                    "formatSettings": {
                        "type": "BinaryReadSettings"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "ForEach1",
                "type": "ForEach",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Get Metadata1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "items": {
                        "value": "@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "isSequential": true,
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "year",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "year",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@substring(split(item().name,'_')[add(length(split(item().name,'_')),-1)],0,4)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "month",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "year",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "month",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@substring(split(item().name,'_')[add(length(split(item().name,'_')),-1)],4,2)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "date",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "month",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "date",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@substring(split(item().name,'_')[add(length(split(item().name,'_')),-1)],6,2)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Copy data1",
                            "type": "Copy",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "date",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "source": {
                                    "type": "BinarySource",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                                        "recursive": true
                                    },
                                    "formatSettings": {
                                        "type": "BinaryReadSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "sink": {
                                    "type": "BinarySink",
                                    "storeSettings": {
                                        "type": "AzureBlobFSWriteSettings"
                                    }
                                },
                                "enableStaging": false
                            },
                            "inputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "copybinarysource",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "filename": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "outputs": [
                                {
                                    "referenceName": "sinkbinary",
                                    "type": "DatasetReference",
                                    "parameters": {
                                        "folder_name": {
                                            "value": "@concat(variables('year'),'/',variables('month'),'/',variables('date'))",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        },
                                        "file_name": {
                                            "value": "@item().name",
                                            "type": "Expression"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "year": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "month": {
                "type": "String"
            },
            "date": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

**Files in target folders:**

[image]

[image]